# How to access DIR615 Router by its Link Local IPv6 address?

Tags: windows-7, networking, google-chrome, router, ipv6

I have DIR 615 router and a desktop with Windows 7 wired to the router. In the router's IPv6 options Link Local is enabled and the link local address mentioned is `FE80::5ED9:98FF:FE5C:518/64`.

In Chrome browser when I try browsing to `http://[FE80::5ED9:98FF:FE5C:518]` it refuses to connect:

[image: Chrome Screenshot]

IPv6 is enabled under Properties for my LAN adapter.

How can I connect to the web interface of my router using its Link Local IPv6 address? IPv4 works just fine.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Your router’s web interface is probably not listening on IPv6.

Comment: I want to check if I can access router's web interface by its Link Local IPv6 address from my Windows 7 PC wired to the router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, well, [that’s a no](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=27234#c2). In the foreseeable future, browsers will not support the required scope/zone identifier in IPv6 URLs.

The [WhatWG URL Standard](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#host-representation) says:

> Support for <zone_id> is intentionally omitted.

So you can either go with Unique Local Addresses (essentially the 192.168.x.y of IPv6) or just forget about IPv6 for the moment. It doesn’t really offer benefits for the average home network.

Answer (score 0):

Link local addresses require the scope id be specified (separated from the address itself with `%`), *i.e.* something like

```
http://[fe80::5ed9:98ff:fe5c:518%5]/
```

might work.  To determine the scope id for each link local interface on your windows machine, issue

```
netsh interface ipv6 show address level=verbose
```

Comment: I think Chrome does not support inclusion of scope id in IPv6 HTTP request. When I try it in Chrome it launches Google search. I tried with IE8  escaping the scope id by 25 like http://[fe80::5ed9:98ff:fe5c:518%2513]/ but it did not work. %13 is the scope id for LAN on Windows 7

Comment: @rajeev, yes I see Chrome failing to allow specifying the (required) scope ID on a link local address.  Does your router allow you to configure a [Unique Local IPv6](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4193) address?  (The scope id will vary by machine.  It is not `%13` for all windows 7 machines.)

Comment: When I use the netsh command as specified by you, for the LAN interface on my Windows 7 PC the scope id is shown as %13 hence I put it there in the URL.

Comment: I am not sure about Unique Local IPv6. ISP offers IPv4 only.

Comment: @rajeev, Unique Local addressing is something you would set up yourself, for local communications.  It would not give you IPv6 internet connectivity, just internal IPv6 (somewhat similar to RFC-1918 IPv4 addresses, like `192.168.xx.yy`).